# What's the purpose of removing an iPhone from Account in icloud.com > settings?

Tags: activation-lock

According to Apple in the article below, you can temporarily remove an iOS device from the list in icloud.com/settings so it doesn’t appear in this list until it goes online again.

I’m curious to know why would anyone ever want to do such a thing.

I’m just trying to grasp the ins and outs of Find my iPhone and Activation Lock.

Any clarification much welcome.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/icloud/mmfc0eeddd/icloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this when I have a device that is lost or stolen. I’ve already documented the serial, filed a police report, sent a remote lock or wipe command. Now it’s time to remove it.

I never expect it back, but Apple has my back and will notify me if it ever comes back online.

I also have some older devices I keep for sentimental reasons. They go in airplane mode, get charged to 50% and powered off, I wake them every 6 months or so to prevent deep discharge of the batteries. No need for them to clutter my list, but they are still under activation lock and my account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've done a bit more research after I saw you answer.  Best thing is to remove it from appleid.apple.com instead of icloud.com/settings as it'll remove it from both appleid.apple.com (this one removes the possibility to use it to get Two Factor Authentication codes) and icloud.com/settings.  Then you'd need to remove it from icloud.com/find which removes Find My iPhone and Activation Lock (either by sending an erase command from there or by just clicking Remove from Account if the device is offline then you can restore it such as with iTunes for Windows or Mac Finder).

Comment: I don’t always do that, though @Antonio23249 I like having options : - )